# Copy file in bash script

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that looking at folder and copy files from one folder to another. 
The scripts is big enough, but here is just a two lines from it:

```
echo cp $working_directory/$folder_name/$f $new_filename
# cp $working_directory/$folder_name/$f $new_filename
```

Here is output of echo command:

```
cp ~/MEGAsync/development/experiments/bash_renamer/tres/a.pdf ~/MEGAsync/development/experiments/bash_renamer/tres_1.pdf
cp ~/MEGAsync/development/experiments/bash_renamer/tres/b.pdf ~/MEGAsync/development/experiments/bash_renamer/tres_2.pdf
```

I can launch any of this command and it works fine in the terminal.
But if I uncomment the real copy command and launch the script I will get the error:

```
cp ~/MEGAsync/development/experiments/bash_renamer/tres/a.pdf ~/MEGAsync/development/experiments/bash_renamer/tres_1.pdf
cp: ~/MEGAsync/development/experiments/bash_renamer/tres/a.pdf: No such file or directory
cp ~/MEGAsync/development/experiments/bash_renamer/tres/b.pdf ~/MEGAsync/development/experiments/bash_renamer/tres_2.pdf
cp: ~/MEGAsync/development/experiments/bash_renamer/tres/b.pdf: No such file or directory
```

Why I have this error and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Try replacing `~` with `"$HOME"`

Comment: In this case all works fine. But why it doesn't work with '~' ?

Comment: Most likely because you quoted `~`, and tilde expansion doesn't happen in quotes. If you did `working_directory=~/` or just `~/$folder_name/$f` it should work. Also, unrelated to the problem, but you really should be quoting your variables to prevent word splitting issues in the future.

Comment: Its how bash interprets ~ sign. The same should work fine in c shell which I use it a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem is with the `~` sign. If the echo prints it as it is, it means, that it looks for directory with name `~` in the working dir. You can replace `~` with `$HOME` or try to execute the command some different way.

Answer (score 2):

This is not working because, most likely, in your `$working_directory` variable definition you have the tilde `~` quoted, thus the *tilde expansion* in bash is not working.

> [**Tilde
>   Expansion**](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html)
>
> If a word begins with an **unquoted tilde** character (‘~’), all of the
>   characters up to the first unquoted slash (or all characters, if there
>   is no unquoted slash) are considered a tilde-prefix. If none of the
>   characters in the tilde-prefix are quoted, the characters in the
>   tilde-prefix following the tilde are treated as a possible login name.
>
> ```
> ~ 
> The value of $HOME
>
> ~/foo 
> $HOME/foo
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the tilde `~` that is part of the variable is not being expanded.
Maybe try doing this first?:

```
eval working_directory=$working_directory
```

Comment: Getting in to the habit of using `evil`, especially when equally simple solutions exist, is likely to cause security holes in the future.

Comment: I'm guessing that typo was intentional?